# Why do I keep getting 138 when I ask for how many times this word appears

Tags: java

I am trying to find how many times a state appears in an one column csv file. It also only prints half of the states. My code is below

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class csvtxt {

   public static void main(String a[]){
      StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
      String strLine = "";
      List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
      try {
         BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\dbb38\\Downloads\\customers_export_111 - customers_export_1 (1).csv"));
         while (strLine != null)
         {
            strLine = br.readLine();
            sb.append(strLine);
            sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
            strLine = br.readLine();
            if (strLine==null)
               break;
            list.add(strLine);
         }
         //
         String wordToSearchFor = "Alabama";
         int Alabama = 0;
         for(String Alabama1 : list)
         {
            if(Alabama1.equals(wordToSearchFor)) 
            {
               Alabama++;
            }
         }
         System.out.println("Alabama = " + "["+ Alabama +"]");
         //
         String wordToSearchFor1 = "Alaska";
         int Alaska = 0;
         for(String Alaska1 : list)
         {
            if(Alaska1.equals(wordToSearchFor)) 
            {
               Alaska++;
            }
         }
         System.out.println("Alaska = " + "["+ Alaska +"]");
         //
         String wordToSearchFor2 = "Arizona";
         int Arizona = 0;
         for(String Arizona1 : list)
         {
            if(Arizona1.equals(wordToSearchFor)) 
            {
               Arizona++;
            }
         }
         System.out.println("Arizona = " + "["+ Arizona +"]");
         //
         System.out.println(Arrays.toString(list.toArray()));
         br.close();
      } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
         System.err.println("File not found");
      } catch (IOException e) {
         System.err.println("Unable to read the file.");
      }
   }
}
```

Here is the output i'm getting. I cut off some of the output because 95881 is too many charaters.

```
Alabama = [138]
Alaska = [138]
Arizona = [138]
[ South Dakota, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Tennessee, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Texas, Utah, Utah, Utah, Utah, Utah, Utah, Utah, Utah, Utah, Utah, Utah, Utah, Utah, Utah, Utah, Utah, Utah, Utah, Utah, Utah, Utah, Utah, Utah, Utah, Utah, Utah, Utah, Utah, Utah, Utah, Utah, Utah, Utah, Utah, Utah, Utah, Utah, Utah, Utah, Utah, Utah, Utah, Utah, Utah, Utah, Utah, Utah, Utah, Utah, Utah, Utah, Utah, Utah, Utah, Utah, Utah, Utah, Utah, Utah, Utah, Utah, Utah, Utah, Utah, Utah, Utah, Utah, Utah, Utah, Utah, Utah, Utah, Utah, Utah, Utah, Utah, Utah, Utah, Utah, Utah, Utah, Utah, Utah, Utah, Utah, Utah, Utah, Utah, Utah, Utah, Utah, Utah, Utah, Utah, Utah, Utah, Utah, Utah, Utah, Utah, Utah, Utah, Utah, Utah, Utah, Utah, Utah, Utah, Utah, Utah, Utah, Utah, Utah, Utah, Utah, Utah, Utah, Utah, Utah, Utah, Utah, Utah, Utah, Utah, Utah, Utah, Utah, Utah, Utah, Utah, Utah, Utah, Utah, Utah, Utah, Utah, Utah, Utah, Utah, Utah, Utah, Utah, Utah, Utah, Utah, Utah, Utah, Utah, Utah, Utah, Utah, Utah, Utah, Utah, Utah, Utah, Utah, Utah, Utah, Utah, Utah, Utah, Utah, Utah, Utah, Utah, Utah, Utah, Utah, Utah, Utah, Utah, Utah, Utah, Utah, Utah, Utah, Utah, Utah, Utah, Utah, Utah, Utah, Utah, Utah, Utah, Utah, Utah, Utah, Utah, Utah, Utah, Utah, Utah, Utah, Utah, Utah, Utah, Vermont, Vermont, Vermont, Vermont, Vermont, Vermont, Vermont, Vermont, Vermont, Vermont, Vermont, Vermont, Vermont, Vermont, Vermont, Vermont, Vermont, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia, Virginia]
```

There is supposed to be 35 Vermont's but it only prints 17 of them. Any help would be appreciated!a

Comment: This has happened because of bad naming of your variables: `wordToSearchFor` , `wordToSearchFor2`,  etc. I recommend you study a bit of code refactoring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
if(Arizona1.equals(wordToSearchFor))
```

with

```
if(Arizona1.equals(wordToSearchFor2))
```

You need to do similar changes for others too. See your mistake ?

Comment: In this case, you should write a comment and vote to close the question as it's about *"a problem that ... was caused by a simple typographical error"* ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)). See also the advice about [answering well-asked questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).